# How does offset work for random forest (regression) in H2O?

Tags: statistics, regression, random-forest, h2o

Mathematically, how does the `offset_column` parameter work during training and during prediction for the random forest algorithm in H2O?

From the docs:

> Note: Offsets are per-row “bias values” that are used during model training. For Gaussian distributions, they can be seen as simple corrections to the response (y) column. Instead of learning to predict the response (y-row), the model learns to predict the (row) offset of the response column. For other distributions, the offset corrections are applied in the linearized space before applying the inverse link function to get the actual response values. For more information, refer to the following link.

Considering that random forests do not have the same concept of 'linearized space', is this any different to applying the offset to the response independently?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

thanks for pointing this out! The offset parameter is actually not supported for H2O's distributed random forest. The parameters will be remove in a future release. A jira ticket for the issue can be found here:https://0xdata.atlassian.net/browse/PUBDEV-5191